# c3.js spline time series chart going backwards

Tags: javascript, d3.js, curve-fitting, c3.js, spline

I am using c3.js to plot out some time series data and the plots its going all over the place doing loops for some reason when there is no need to loop.

Here is the view of all 5 of the plots I am plotting
[image]

taking a closer look at just one of them we can see that it loops backward even though there are no points backwards.

[image]

I know it is because of the fitting algorithm, but I am not sure how to fix it. I am not using any other configuration for c3 other than just setting data and spline.

To reproduce the issue and see for yourself, you can try [this page](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_spline.html), and replace the snippet with the following:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['X', 1, 2, 3.9, 4, 5, 6],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 15, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        x: 'X',
        type: 'spline'
    }
});
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see a [mcve]

Comment: I said in the post I am using the basic plot with no extra config. So here is my code: http://c3js.org/samples/chart_spline.html

Comment: Okay, if Joe Random Helper visits that link, what would he need to do in the snippet to see what you see?

Comment: You can see from the first graph that there are multiple loops happening from the curve fitting algorithm. The second picture shows 3 points from one specific plot that does not go backward, however, the plot fitting algorithm is going backward in a loop. I am not asking for someone to fix my code, I am asking for someone who knows how this specific curve fitting algorithm works and why it would loop backward, and what algorithm within c3 (or d3) that I would need to use so it is a smooth curve through all points and not loop backwards.

Comment: All I'm saying is if you can show a concrete example, you will get better help. Without this, the question is too vague and might get flagged as such. Please read [ask] and [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Answer (score 1):

I found this question interesting, so yesterday I added a concrete example to the question, which reproduces the issue with 2 consecutive points being very close on X axis, which triggers c3 to generate splines that "go backwards".

Spline interpolation is delegated to `d3`, and defaults to [`cardinal`](https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/c3553a6c9e18f652a5226a4f83f2ef7f6e88293d/c3.js#L4585) type, but that can be changed in c3 like so:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['X', 1, 2, 3.9, 4, 5, 6],
            ['dataA', 30, 200, 100, 401, 15, 250],
            ['dataB', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        x: 'X',
        type: 'spline'
    },
    spline: {
        interpolation: {
            type: 'basis'
        }
    }
});
```

See [this page](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/smoothing-out-lines-in-d3js.html) for other options: `'linear', 'linear-closed', 'basis', 'basis-open', 'basis-closed', 'bundle', 'cardinal', 'cardinal-open', 'cardinal-closed', 'monotone'`.

With `d3`, In order to get splines that are monotone on X axis, you would need to play with the `tension` parameter, which can go from `0.0` to `1.0` and defaults to `0.7` (for close points on X axis, you need high values close to `1.0`). See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xqnj05s/), play with `.tension(0.3)`, see how curve changes.

Unfortunately that does not seem to be exposed in `c3`. That might be a valid issue to suggest to their GitHub. But it would not be so easy because if your data has varying steps on X axis (like in example), you'd need a non-constant `tension`, and as far as I know that can only be implemented with a custom interpolation function in d3 (all the more unlikely to be exposed in c3).